# SQL counting customers that have ordered the same product at least 7 times

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have the following tables

– Price (**prodID**, from, price)

– Product (**prodID**, name, quantity)

– PO (**prodID**, **orderID**, amount)

– Order (**orderID**, date, address, status, trackingNumber, custID, shipID)

– Shipping (**shipID**, company, time, price)

– Customer (**custID**, name)

– Address (**addrID**, custID, address)

I would like to find the names of customers who have bought the same item at least 7 times, if they bought the same item twice in one order I would like to count it as one. Here is my code:

```
SELECT C.name, COUNT(DISTINCT p.prodId) as prod_count
FROM Product P
INNER JOIN PO
ON PO.prodId = P.prodId
INNER JOIN "Order" O
ON O.orderId = PO.orderId
INNER JOIN Customer C
ON C.custId = O.custId
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.prodId) > 6;
```

However, this is returning the number of unique products each customer has ordered which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You need to group by the customer and the product - it's not clear what table it would be but this will give you the counts for customer and product where there have been more than 6 orders

Answer (score 1):

We can try using two levels of aggregation here.  The first level of aggregation is by customer, order, and product, and removes duplicates should a given customer order the same product more than once within a single order.  The next level of aggregation is only by customer and product, and it retains only customers who have at least one product which they purchased 7 or more times across different orders.  Finally, we do a distinct select to retain each unique matching customer name.

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT c.name, o.orderId, p.prodId
    FROM Customer c
    INNER JOIN "Order" o ON o.custId = c.custId
    INNER JOIN PO po ON po.orderId = o.orderId
    INNER JOIN Product p ON p.prodId = po.prodId
    GROUP BY c.name, o.orderId, p.prodId
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT name, prodId
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY name, prodId
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 7
)

SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM cte2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see , there is no need of joining with `Product` table,unless you need `Product` name in your result.

```
;with CTE as(
    SELECT orderId,prodId, COUNT(*) as OrderProd_Count
    FROM dbo.PO
    GROUP BY orderId,prodId
    )
    ,CTE1 as(
    SELECT prodId,count(*) as Prod_Count
    from CTE
    group by prodId
    having count(*)>7
    )
    select c1.productid,ca.Name from CTE1 C1
    inner join CTE C on c1.prodId=c1.prodId
    inner join dbo.Order O on c.orderid=O.orderId
    inner join Customer  C on o.custid=C.custid
```